# Why when I'm only changing a variable in my query that makes that it takes a long time to run?

Tags: sql-server

The first thing I would like to say is that, this is not exactly what I'm trying to achieve.
I extracted this part of the entire query because here is the problem.

I've two nearly identical queries, when I run the first one, it works in aprox 1-2 minutes.
But the second query takes much more time (I don't know how much time, but is too much)
Here are the queries.

The first one:

```
DECLARE @IdNegocio int
SET @IdNegocio = 3

SELECT 
      Test.CantidadDeCuotasElUltimoAño
    , Test.SUMA
    , sa.AcumSumas
    , test.NumeroDocumento
FROM (
       SELECT 
             COUNT(cu.Id) AS CantidadDeCuotasElUltimoAño
           , SUM(cu.Monto) AS SUMA
           , cli.NumeroDocumento 
           , cli.CUIT
       FROM dbo.Cuota cu 
            INNER JOIN Contrato c ON cu.idAutomovil = c.idAutomovil
            INNER JOIN Cliente cli ON cli.idAutomovil = c.idAutomovil
            INNER JOIN Automovil au on au.Id = c.idAutomovil
            INNER JOIN Seguro seg ON seg.idAutomovil = c.idAutomovil AND seg.Estado4NH = 1
       WHERE cli.idNegocio = @IdNegocio AND 
             c.EstadoContrato4NH = 1 AND 
             c.TipoContrato4NH != 3 AND 
             cu.VigenciaDesde >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12,GETDATE()) AND
             cu.VigenciaDesde <= GETDATE() AND
             seg.Id IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY cli.NumeroDocumento
               , cli.CUIT
    ) AS Test 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(au.SumaAsegurada) AcumSumas
                , cli.NumeroDocumento   
                , cli.CUIT       
            FROM Cliente cli
                INNER JOIN Contrato c ON cli.idAutomovil = c.idAutomovil
                INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Numero) Ultima, idAutomovil FROM Cuota cuo GROUP BY idAutomovil) AS UltimasCuotas ON UltimasCuotas.idAutomovil = cli.idAutomovil
                INNER JOIN Cuota cuo ON cuo.Numero = UltimasCuotas.Ultima AND cuo.idAutomovil = UltimasCuotas.idAutomovil
                INNER JOIN Automovil au on au.Id = cli.idAutomovil
                INNER JOIN Seguro seg ON seg.idAutomovil = cli.idAutomovil AND seg.Estado4NH = 1
            WHERE cli.idNegocio = @IdNegocio AND 
                c.EstadoContrato4NH = 1 AND 
                c.TipoContrato4NH != 3 AND 
                cuo.VigenciaDesde >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12,GETDATE()) AND
                seg.Id IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY cli.NumeroDocumento
                    , cli.CUIT              ) AS Sa ON sa.NumeroDocumento = Test.NumeroDocumento AND sa.CUIT = Test.CUIT
```

The second one:

```
DECLARE @IdNegocio int
SET @IdNegocio = 12

SELECT 
      Test.CantidadDeCuotasElUltimoAño
    , Test.SUMA
    , sa.AcumSumas
    , test.NumeroDocumento
FROM (
       SELECT 
             COUNT(cu.Id) AS CantidadDeCuotasElUltimoAño
           , SUM(cu.Monto) AS SUMA
           , cli.NumeroDocumento 
           , cli.CUIT
       FROM dbo.Cuota cu 
            INNER JOIN Contrato c ON cu.idAutomovil = c.idAutomovil
            INNER JOIN Cliente cli ON cli.idAutomovil = c.idAutomovil
            INNER JOIN Automovil au on au.Id = c.idAutomovil
            INNER JOIN Seguro seg ON seg.idAutomovil = c.idAutomovil AND seg.Estado4NH = 1
       WHERE cli.idNegocio = @IdNegocio AND 
             c.EstadoContrato4NH = 1 AND 
             c.TipoContrato4NH != 3 AND 
             cu.VigenciaDesde >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12,GETDATE()) AND
             cu.VigenciaDesde <= GETDATE() AND
             seg.Id IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY cli.NumeroDocumento
               , cli.CUIT
    ) AS Test 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(au.SumaAsegurada) AcumSumas
                , cli.NumeroDocumento   
                , cli.CUIT       
            FROM Cliente cli
                INNER JOIN Contrato c ON cli.idAutomovil = c.idAutomovil
                INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Numero) Ultima, idAutomovil FROM Cuota cuo GROUP BY idAutomovil) AS UltimasCuotas ON UltimasCuotas.idAutomovil = cli.idAutomovil
                INNER JOIN Cuota cuo ON cuo.Numero = UltimasCuotas.Ultima AND cuo.idAutomovil = UltimasCuotas.idAutomovil
                INNER JOIN Automovil au on au.Id = cli.idAutomovil
                INNER JOIN Seguro seg ON seg.idAutomovil = cli.idAutomovil AND seg.Estado4NH = 1
            WHERE cli.idNegocio = @IdNegocio AND 
                c.EstadoContrato4NH = 1 AND 
                c.TipoContrato4NH != 3 AND 
                cuo.VigenciaDesde >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12,GETDATE()) AND
                seg.Id IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY cli.NumeroDocumento
                    , cli.CUIT              ) AS Sa ON sa.NumeroDocumento = Test.NumeroDocumento AND sa.CUIT = Test.CUIT
```

The only change between both is IdNegocio, are the same tables, the same structure.

Moreover the firstone takes arrownd 68k registers and de second one should be more or less 30k.

Here is the execution plan for the slow query.

[Execution_plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkapazfVV)

I'm executing it in an SQL server with the next especifications:
    Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)   Apr 29 2016 23:23:58   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Your title confuses me, there are no variables in your SQL (a variable starts with an `@`). Also, how long is a "king" time?

Comment: On a different note, you *might* want to consider turning that `INNER JOIN` to a subquery to a `CROSS APPLY` with a correlated subquery. Otherwise, I suggest posting the DDL (with indexes) for your tables and the execution plans for the slow running query using Paste The Plan.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu , I changed the title and I put the variables for be more clarify

Comment: This seems like it could be greatly simplified. I don't see any reason to have these two sub queries. But without a ton more detail nobody can help here. We need to see an execution plan. Possibly the table definitions (including indexes) and approximate row counts. To be honest, I would argue your first query is not even close to working acceptable if it takes 1-2 minutes.

Comment: @Larnu I don't know how can I paste the plan.
Sorry, I'm a beginner here.
Can you explain to me how can I do it?

Comment: [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Thanks @Larnu , The execution plan has been added.

Comment: I checked your plan and the heaviest part is the first derived table. Consider moving the joins to tables Contrato, Automovil and Seguro to an EXISTS clause, as they serve only to filter data and are not part of the output,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has solved my problem, the answer for me was TVF (Table-valued Functions).
I maked a TVF for each sub-query and joined each one in the master query.
Thanks!

Here is a piece of it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CantidadDeContratos](@IdNegocio tinyint)
RETURNS @tmpCantidadDeContratos TABLE (
            CantidadContratos int
                , NumeroDocumento varchar(20)
                , CUIT varchar(20)
)
AS

BEGIN 
INSERT INTO @tmpCantidadDeContratos
SELECT COUNT(con.idAutomovil) CantidadContratos
                        , cli.NumeroDocumento, cli.CUIT
                    FROM Contrato con
                        INNER JOIN Cliente cli ON cli.idAutomovil = con.idAutomovil
                    WHERE cli.idNegocio = @IdNegocio AND 
                         con.EstadoContrato4NH = 1 AND 
                         con.TipoContrato4NH != 3
                    GROUP BY cli.NumeroDocumento
                            , cli.CUIT
    RETURN
END 

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer uses statistics to estimate how many rows will match your IdNegocio value and it will create a query plan that should be best for that situation.

If your statistics are stale, these estimates may be bad. If so, this can result in a poor query plan.

To update all statistics of your database, run:

```
EXEC sp_updatestats
```

The command will report whether or not it has updated your table's statistics.